# Parameter is invalid exception when retrieving image from database to picturebox

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, winforms

I am retrieving the image from a SQL Server database into a `PictureBox` in a C# Windows application. The image is a form which I don't know.

I tried this code but it throws a "parameter invalid" exception, and I also go through many answer related to this but didn't work any.

My code:

```
  SqlConnection sql_con  = new SqlConnection();
  sql_con.ConnectionString = @"Server=abc-14;Database=Abcstudent;User Id=sa; Password=abc;";

  if (sql_con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
      sql_con.Open();

  try
  {
      string query = "Select grno, PICStudent from GENREG where grno = 1";                        
      SqlCommand sql_cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sql_con);

      sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      SqlDataAdapter sql_adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_cmd);               
      sql_adp.Fill(sql_ds);    
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
  }

  // code for retrieving image to picture box 
  try
  {
       DataRow myRow;
       byte[] MyData = new byte[0];
       myRow = sql_ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

       MyData = (byte[])myRow["PICStudent"];
       MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(MyData);
       pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);  // getting error here
  }
  catch()
  {
  }
```

Database Image 
[image]

Comment: In which line of code you are getting the error?

Comment: I update  question with line of error in comments

Answer (score 1):

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select picbox from picture1 where id=1", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["picbox"]);
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
        }
```

Comment: thank you @vinoth but same error : parameter invalid

Comment: in which line@Mamta

Comment: pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms) // Parameter Invalid

Comment: I didn't know the type of image in database like jpg , png etc but datatypes is Image in table

Answer (score 1):

Insead of using Image.FromStream, did you try using ImageConverter?

Sample come of using ImageConverter looks as following.

```
byte[] filedata = (byte[])myRow["PICStudent"];
ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
System.Drawing.Image image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(fileData) as System.Drawing.Image;
image.Save(imageFullPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This should resolve your issue.

Thanks and regards,
Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: thank you for answer @Chetan but getting error "Parameter Invalid " in imageConverter.ConvertFrom(fileData) as System.Drawing.Image ;